# Where could I download Pre-Packaged Identity Server 5.1.0 with API Manager 1.10.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Should be an easy question ;)
In the WSO 2 Clustering & Deployment Guide, Configuring the Identity Server 5.1.0 as a Key Manager with API Manager 1.10.0, it is recommended to install the pre-packaged WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 with the API Manager as most of the configurations already exist in the pre-packaged distribution.

Where can I download this pre-packaged WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 ?
In the product page, there is only a Download button with no choice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [link](http://product-dist.wso2.com/downloads/api-manager/1.10.0/identity-server/wso2is-5.1.0.zip) to download the pre-packaged Identity Server. However the link to download this is available in the [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.1.0+with+API+Manager+1.10.0) under the section "Configuring the Identity Server" step 1.

Comment: Thank you Jason. I'll put my glasses next time ;)